# Use traits to invert dependencies

Tags: rust

Im new to Rust and I'm trying to implement a Conway's game of life. The structure is simple:

```rust
pub struct Grid {
  grid: Vec<Vec<bool>>,
  size: i16,
  age: i64,
}

impl Grid {
  pub fn new(size: i16) -> Self { ... }
  pub fn update_field(&mut self, cell: Cell) { ... }
  pub fn update_many(&mut self, cells: Vec<Cell>) { ... }
  pub fn get_liveness(&self, cell: &dyn Cell) -> bool { ... }
  pub fn mutate(&mut self) { ... }
// In my opinion implementations are irrelevant here, but i can show it here with no problems
}
```

But my doubt is about `Cell`. Cell is a trait

```rust
pub trait Cell {
  fn new(x: i16, y: i16, size: i16) -> Result<Self, String>;
  fn get_neighborhood(&self) -> Vec<Self>;
}
```

That knows how to calculate neighbors. I want this segregated because I want to implement game of life in different topologies (i.e, a vanilla implementation in a plane, a implementation in a sphere surface, maybe in a torus etc). So, the Grid class can be unique, differente `Cell` implementations would just know how to calculate neighborhood in different surfaces. But I'm gettind the error `"trait objects must include the dyn keyword"`, and if I add it then i get the error `"the trait domain::grid::Cell cannot be made into an object consider moving get_neighborhood to another trait"`. What am I missing here?

I think the central point is that im trying to use traits as a kind of interface, and Im not sure if it is the same thing. I would be grateful if, in addition to help, I could have some reference to go deeper and understand what is happening. I'm following the book "The rust programming language" but I still couldn't understand what the problem is here.

Comment: Use generics, i.e. static polymorphism, instead of `dyn` (dynamic polymorphism). It'll make your life a whole lot easier.

Answer (score 3):

This function `pub fn update_many(&mut self, cells: Vec<Cell>)` (if hypothetically it compiled) takes any combination of cells, potentially of different types (i.e. different topology). Based on your description of your problem domain, this is wrong - each grid update can only operate on a collection of cells of uniform type, and also that type should match the actual cell type of the grid.

You should use static polymorphism here, not dynamic polymorphism (the `dyn` keyword). You should add a type parameter to Grid and bound it by the `Cell` trait:

```
use std::marker::PhantomData;

pub struct Grid<C> {
  grid: Vec<Vec<bool>>,
  size: i16,
  age: i64,
  data : PhantomData<C> // you should actually store Cells within your Grid so you shouldn't need PhantomData
}


impl<C : Cell> Grid<C> {
  pub fn new(size: i16) -> Self { todo!()  }
  pub fn update_field(&mut self, cell: C) { todo!() }
  pub fn update_many(&mut self, cells: Vec<C>) {todo!() }
  pub fn get_liveness(&self, cell: C) -> bool { todo!() }
  pub fn mutate(&mut self) { todo!()  }
}

pub trait Cell : Sized {
  fn new(x: i16, y: i16, size: i16) -> Result<Self, String>;
  fn get_neighborhood(&self) -> Vec<Self>;
}
```

Comment: You don't necessarily need to add a type parameter to `Grid`, it may be easier to only use type parameters in the methods.

Comment: Chayim's suggestion worked perfectly for me. I think that only methods that actually need to calculate a neighborhood should depend on `<C: Cell>`. Worked perfectly.

Comment: It will depend on whether or not a single `Grid` type can operate on different types of `Cells`. Based on my understanding of the problem, that's not the case.